# Controlling axis ticks and axis lines separately on R lattice xyplot

Tags: r, axis, lattice

How can I go about removing the box around an `xyplot`, while keeping the axis scale tick marks? In the spirit of Edward Tufte's minimalist data graphic aesthetic, these axis lines are "non-data ink," and can (should?) be "erased."

```
library(lattice)
my.df <- data.frame(x=-10:10)
my.df$y <- my.df$x^2
xyplot(y~x,data=my.df)
```

[image: standard xyplot output]

It seems that the trellis display parameters (e.g. `axis.line$col`) control both the axis lines and axis ticks together:

```
xyplot(y~x,data=my.df,
       par.settings=list(axis.line=list(col="transparent")))
```

[image: with axis.line$col="transparent"]

...which is not the desired result, so it doesn't look like there's a simple way to turn off the lines while leaving the box.

The best I've been able to come up with is a brute-force hack, where I build the tick marks by hand using `panel.segments`:

```
at.x=pretty(c(-10,10))
at.y=pretty(c(0,100))
xyplot(y~x,data=my.df,
       par.settings=list(axis.line=list(col="transparent")),
       scales=list(x=list(at=at.x,labels=at.x),
       y=list(at=at.y,labels=at.y)),
       panel=function(...){
           panel.xyplot(...)
           panel.segments(x0=at.x,x1=at.x,y0=-4,y1=-2)
           panel.segments(x0=-11.5,x1=-11,y0=at.y,y1=at.y)
       }
       )
```

[image: hand-made tick marks with panel.segments]

This is close to the desired result, but there's quite a bit of fiddling required to get the tick marks to be a reasonable length and offset a "nice" distance from the data points. These values won't translate from one graphic to the next. Plus, note that the axis labels are now padded too far from the tick marks. I'm sure there's a way to reduce that padding, but that would only make the code even uglier and less portable.

So how can one go about suppressing just the lines that make up the "box" around the plot area, while leaving the tick marks and axis labels intact? Bonus points if this approach could also be used to suppress some, but not all of the lines (e.g. leave the left and lower lines, but suppress the top and right lines).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is still a bit hacky, but at least you don't have to do any figuring by hand. It uses a combination of `par.settings` and a custom `axis` function that takes an argument `line.col` and temporarily changes the axis line color by a call to `trellis.par.set`:

**EDIT** (removed unnecessary changing of trellis settings)

```
xyplot(y~x,data=my.df, par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")),
  # Pass custom axis function to argument 'axis'
  axis = function(side, line.col = "black", ...) {
    # Only draw axes on the left and bottom
    if(side %in% c("left","bottom")) {
      # Call default axis drawing function
      axis.default(side = side, line.col = "black", ...)
    }
  }
)
```

At the moment, I chalk up why `line.col = "black"` is required in the arguments of the custom axis function to magic. My guess is that it has to do with argument matching with the ellipses (`...`). Perhaps I'll be wiser tomorrow and find the true reason.

This results in:

[image]

Comment: This looks great. Would you mind providing a little commentary about what each line of the axis function does and why you're doing it? I'm finding the help documentation on the low-level axis functions (like `axis.default` aren't very enlightening .

Comment: @mac, Turns out there was some unnecessary changing of trellis options, and the true trick seems to be to provide the custom axis function a formal argument `line.col`.

Comment: Nice. FWIW, `line.col = "black"` is needed because `panel.axis()` by default takes its line color from `trellis.par.get("axis.line")`, which you've earlier set to `"transparent"`.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest thing to do is to use the custom axis function (axis). Just set lwd (line width) to zero and tick marks (lwd.ticks) to something else. It worked like a charm!

```
plot(NA,NA,type="n",xaxt="n", lwd=linewidth, xlim=c(1,24), xlab="", ylab="",ylim=c(-300,500))
axis(side = 4, tck = .05, **lwd=0, lwd.ticks=1**, line = 0, labels = NA, col= cols_border[1], col.axis = cols_black)
axis(side = 4, lwd = 0, line = -4.5, las = 1, cex.axis=axis_fontsize, col= cols_border[1], col.axis = cols_black)
mtext("Light deviations (lum/sec)",side=4, padj=-2.5, cex=title_fontsize, col="black")
```

Comment: This uses base graphics, whereas the OP is using the `lattice` package.