# remove panel outline / add axis ticks and colour scale outline in lattice wireframe plots

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a series of wireplots, similar to the example below;

```
require(lattice)

# set up some data
theta <- seq(-3, 3, .4)
data <- expand.grid(theta, theta)
data$z <- dnorm(data[,1]) * dnorm(data[,2])
names(data) <- c('x','y','z')

# plot it
wireframe(z ~ x * y, data,
          scales = list( arrows = FALSE),
          aspect = c(1, .6),
          drape = TRUE)
```

Which gives the below plot.

[image: wireframe with panel bounding box]

I would like to remove the panel outline. The standard solution is to use `par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = 'transparent'))`;

```
# try to remove outline
wireframe(z ~ x * y, data,
          scales = list( arrows = FALSE),
          aspect = c(1, .6),
          drape = TRUE,
          par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = 'transparent')))
```

Which does indeed remove the outline, but doesn't stop there...

[image]

Axis tick marks as well as the outline around the colour scale are removed too. Solutions are available for 2d plots, see for example [Controlling axis ticks and axis lines separately on R lattice xyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901396/controlling-axis-ticks-and-axis-lines-separately-on-r-lattice-xyplot) , but I have been unable to find a similar solution for 3d/wireframe plots.

I've tried fiddling around with providing an axis function as per the above answer, but it appears that function only gets called for top/bottom/left/right, which would not be very useful for a 3d plot.

## Questions;

How can I stop lattice from removing tick marks and the scale outline when setting `par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = 'transparent'))`?

Failing that, what function is used for tick marks on a wireframe plot, and what function is used for the outline on the colour scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do the job.

```
wireframe(z ~ x * y, data,
          scales = list( arrows = FALSE, col="black"), # col="black" is required 
          aspect = c(1, .6),
          drape = TRUE,
          par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = 'transparent'))
)
```

This is adapted from [Seth W Bigelow's answer](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Eliminate-border-in-wireframe-plot-td1593825.html)

Comment: Ugh, so simple - can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Also needed adding a specific color for the outline of the colorkey;
    `colorkey = list(height = .8, axis.line = list(col = 'black'))`, which wasn't part of the question but was part of my problem.