# Hide top x-axis in doubleYScale plot in R

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I'm plotting two xyplots with a doubleYScale plot. I would like to hide the top x-axis, but everything I tried so far either does nothing or hides all axes. Is this even possible?

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
x<-seq(1:10)
y<-x^2
y2<-x*2

plot1<-xyplot(y~x, col="black", type="l", ylab="Label1", xlab="") 

plot2<-xyplot(y2~x, col="red", type="l", ylab="Label2", xlab="", scales=list(y=list(col="red")))

doubleYScale(plot1, plot2, add.axis=TRUE, add.ylab2 = TRUE, scales=list(x=list(draw=FALSE)))  

update(trellis.last.object(),
par.settings = simpleTheme(col = c("black", "red"), lty=c(1,1)), horizontal=F, scales=list(x=list(draw=T)))
```

[image: doubleYScale plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the proposed solution below, **lattice** isn't really set up to easily do this particular thing. That said, it's pretty fully customizable, and with some work you can get what you're after. Here, with just a few inline comments, is code that will fully suppress that top axis:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
library(grid)

## Sample data
x <- seq(1:10)
y <- x^2
y2 <- x*2

## Prepare list of scales setting that suppresses ticks on top axis
myScales <- list(x = list(tck = c(1,0)))

## Prepare parameter settings, including setting the color used in
## plotting axis line to "transparent"
myTheme <- simpleTheme(col = c("black", "red"),
                       lty = c(1,1))
myTheme <- c(myTheme, list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")))

## Write a custom axis function that only plots axis lines on the
## left, right, and bottom sides
myAxisFun <- function(side, line.col, ...) {
    if (side == "left") {
        grid.lines(x = c(0, 0), y = c(0, 1),
                   default.units = "npc")
    } else if (side == "right") {
        grid.lines(x = c(1, 1), y = c(0, 1),
                   default.units = "npc")
    } else if (side == "bottom") {
        grid.lines(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 0),
                   default.units = "npc")
    }
    axis.default(side = side, line.col = "black", ...)
}


## Construct two component plots
plot1 <- xyplot(y ~ x, col="black", type = "l",
                ylab = "Label1", xlab = "",
                par.settings = myTheme,
                scales = myScales,
                axis = myAxisFun) 
plot2 <- xyplot(y2 ~ x, col="red", type = "l",
                ylab = "Label2", xlab = "",
                par.settings = myTheme,
                scales = myScales,
                axis = myAxisFun)

## Meld the two plots 
doubleYScale(plot1, plot2, add.ylab2 = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: This removes the upper ticks, but not the axis (panel box?). I may have misworded, by apologies. Thanks for reorganizing. I tried to have all those arguments within the xyplot calls, but for some reason it wasn't working for me. I'm still learning how to deal with lattice and it's very confusing.

Comment: @Anke OK -- based on your clarification, I changed my answer. Not nearly as user friendly as being able to do `plot(1:10, bty = "u")`, but it'll get the job done and perhaps teach you a bit more about how **lattice** works, under the hood.

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually did come across the axis function before, but couldn't get it to work and didn't quite know how to modify it correctly. Using your solution, I get the following error message: 

Error in x$axis(side = "left", scales = x$y.scales, components = yscale.comps,  : 
  could not find function "grid.lines

Comment: @Anke -- That's because I neglected to include a call to `library(grid)`. Just fixed that, so it should now work.

Comment: Loading the grid library did the trick (duh, could've noticed myself). Thank you so much, this is perfect!

Comment: Ok, one last question (I'm going through the code trying to understand what every single commant line is doing. lattice seriously isn't intuitive), is there any way to get the tick marks back on the x-axis that is being displayed?

Comment: @Anke -- Darned if I know! I agree, it can be frustrating.

Comment: I got it with the help of this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901396/controlling-axis-ticks-and-axis-lines-separately-on-r-lattice-xyplot. I had to add line.col = "black" in the axis function.

Comment: @Anke Thanks! I've now edited my answer to include that improvement.

Comment: I could use some more help. I tried reading in the lattice documentation, but I'm really lost. I'm trying to change font sizes. It works fine with including "fontsize" in list(par.main.text = list(font = 1, just = "left", x = grid::unit(5, "mm"), fontsize=16)) when setting up the theme, but for axis.text only cex works but not fontsize, and nothing so far for the axis labels. What am I missing.

Comment: @Anke -- Looks to me like the issue with `par.ylab.text` not accepting (and properly passing through a `fontsize` argument) in the same way as `par.main.text` is the fault of `doubleYScale()`. You can get it to properly handle the `fontsize` specification for the ylab on the left axis by doing `doubleYScale(plot1, plot2, add.ylab2 = TRUE, use.style = FALSE)`, but it doesn't properly pass through the same parameter for the ylab on the right axis.

Comment: @Anke -- As for `axis.text`, the reason it won't pass on a `fontsize` parameter is that it gets processed by `calculateGridLayout()`, which handles a fixed set of parameters that does not happen to include `fontsize`. `par.ylab.text` and `par.main.text`, by contrast, get processed by  `grobFromLabelList()`, which passes along arbitrary additional arguments (like `fontsize`) to `gpar()` via a `...` argument. I'm guessing that all is deeper in the weeds than you're wanting to go, but just wanted to leave these pointers in case you want to look into the source files yourself.