# Make certain lines invisible in lattice plot

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I have a graph generated with the following code:

```
require(lattice)
mydata <- data.frame(y = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.23, 0.17, 0.27), x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
ticks_at <- seq(-0.5, 0, 0.1)
barchart(-y ~ x, 
         mydata, 
         horizontal = FALSE, 
         origin=0, 
         scales = list(y=list(at = ticks_at, 
                              labels = -1 * (ticks_at)),
                       alternating = 2,
                       tck = c(0,1)),
         xlab = "x",
         ylab ="y")
```

I want to do two things: a) I want x-axis to have ticks (right now only y-axis has ticks, as you can see), b) I want to remove left and top axis lines so that graph only has bottom and right axis. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding ticks to the bottom but not top x-axis can be done by adding the following to the `scales = list(...)` portion of your code.

```
x = list(tck = c(1, 0))
```

**Eliminating** the top and/or side axis is not so simple with `lattice`. You can create a custom axis function to replace the left, right, top and bottom components provide by `axis.default()`. This has been described in [Hide top x-axis in doubleYScale plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52955237/3508856). I am a big fan of lattice but would be inclined to use base graphics for what you want:

```
# Starting with values in mydata and ticks_at
  opar <- par(mar = c(5,2,2,5) + 0.1)
  mp <- barplot(-mydata$y, axes = FALSE, col = "cyan", xlab = "x")
  axis(1, at = mp, line = 1, labels = mydata$x) # or explicit labels if needed
  axis(4, las = 1, at = ticks_at, labels = -ticks_at)
  title(ylab = "y", line = 0) # mtext could be used to place "y" on the right
  par(opar)
```