# removing the ticks on the 3rd and 4th axes in plots from library effects in R

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I'm wondering if there is a way to remove the tickmarks (the axes) on the 3rd and 4th axes of the plot generated by library `effects` as shown below?

```
library(effects)
m <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss)
plot(allEffects(m), rug = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: sounds like that is what the `alternating` argument is for, but it doesn't seem to do anything. judging by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52955975/2994949), it looks like some work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't look like the package authors choose to expose that propertly very easily. We could write our own version of `plot.efflist` which is doing most of the work here. Here's the alternative version

```
plot.efflist <- function (x, selection, rows, cols, graphics = TRUE, 
          lattice, ...) 
{
  lattice <- if (missing(lattice)) 
    list()
  else lattice
  if (!missing(selection)) {
    if (is.character(selection)) 
      selection <- gsub(" ", "", selection)
    pp <- plot(x[[selection]], lattice = lattice, ...)
    pp$x.scales$tck=c(1,0)
    pp$y.scales$tck=c(1,0)
    return(pp)
  }
  effects <- gsub(":", "*", names(x))
  neffects <- length(x)
  mfrow <- mfrow(neffects)
  if (missing(rows) || missing(cols)) {
    rows <- mfrow[1]
    cols <- mfrow[2]
  }
  for (i in 1:rows) {
    for (j in 1:cols) {
      if ((i - 1) * cols + j > neffects) 
        break
      more <- !((i - 1) * cols + j == neffects)
      lattice[["array"]] <- list(row = i, col = j, 
                                 nrow = rows, ncol = cols, more = more)
      pp <- plot(x[[(i - 1) * cols + j]], lattice = lattice, 
                 ...)
      # hack to turn off opposite side tick marks
      pp$x.scales$tck=c(1,0)
      pp$y.scales$tck=c(1,0)
      print(pp)
    }
  }
}
environment(plot.efflist) <- asNamespace("effects")
```

Basically we just call the `plot.eff` function as is, then modify the result to turn off the second set of ticks before plotting.

This returns

```
plot(allEffects(m), rug = FALSE)
```

[image]

Optionally you could try this approach as well

```
plot.eff <- function(...) {
  pp <- effects:::plot.eff(...)
  pp$x.scales$tck=c(1,0)
  pp$y.scales$tck=c(1,0)
  pp
}
environment(plot.eff) <- asNamespace("effects")
helpenv <- new.env(parent = asNamespace("effects"))
helpenv$plot.eff <- plot.eff
plot.efflist <- effects:::plot.efflist
environment(plot.efflist) <- helpenv
```

Here, rather than changing just the function that operators on `efflist` objects, we change the behavior for all `eff` objects. We do the rewrite but then also need to change the `efflist` version to find our new version first. This method keeps us from having to repeat any logic from these functions, but it does mean we make a bit of a mess with environments.

Comment: [nearly 1000 lines of code](https://github.com/cran/effects/blob/master/R/plot-methods.R#L123:L1006) down to 35, that's pretty good golfing

Comment: @rawr I still use `plot.eff` as is and then modify the lattice object it returns. I didn't touch that. I just focused on `plot.efflist` which needed to be hacked because it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I have asked a follow-up question on your answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65971155/7223434). In case interested, I would appreciate it if you could possibly take a look at it.