# Personalize the color of the confidence interval bars of an plot.effects() R

Tags: r, colors, confidence-interval

Good morning,
I'm talking about plot.effects of the R package "effects", https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/effects.pdf

I would like to personalize the color of the confidence interval bars of an plot.effects().

confint=list(style="bars",color="black") looks not working, the parameters of the colors of the confidence intervals are taken from the color of lines.

This is the code I use:

```
#remove all the axis
trellis.par.set(list(axis.line = list(col = c(0))))
my.theme <- list(
  axis.components = list(top = list(tck = 0, pad1 = 0, pad2 = 0),
                       right = list(tck = 0,pad1 = 0, pad2 = 0)))
trellis.par.set(theme = my.theme)

#add only bottom and left axis  
myAxisFun <- function(side, line.col, ...) {
  if (side == "left") {
    grid.lines(x = c(0, 0), y = c(0, 1), default.units = "npc")
  } else if (side == "bottom") {
    grid.lines(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 0), default.units = "npc")
  }
  axis.default(side = side, line.col = 1, ...)  
}


plot(A2[1],main="Interaction between Subtopic and Condition",ylab="Response Accuracy",
     lines=list(multiline=T,col=c( "#CC6677","#332288", "#88CCEE"),lty=1:3,lwd=c(2,2,2)),
     confint=list(style="bars",color="black"), #add the confidence interval
     #band.colors=c("black","black","black"), 
     #residuals.color="black",
     #confint.col="black",
     axis = myAxisFun,
     symbols=list(pch=c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1))) #remove simbols
```

Commented inside the function there are the other parameters I tried to set, without any results.

Maybe the solution is a personalized function as I used to the axis? (reference [Hide top x-axis in doubleYScale plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52955237/hide-top-x-axis-in-doubleyscale-plot-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1))

The blue arrow point to one of the band which I would change the color.

[result of the previous code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go0uj.png)

I hope the request is enough clear, thanks to everyone who could help.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I find a suboptimal solution which consist of modify the colors of the bar in the PDF printed graph using [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/). That program allows you to do not lose the PDF quality of the image and manually adjust the details who you need.